# MVC2 HttpPostedFileBase object is always nothing

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-2, file-upload

I tried to recreate the thousands of simple examples online, and I Fail everytime.

What am I doing wrong?

- Other.aspx

  > ```
  > <%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"
  > ```
  >
  > Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
  >
  > ```
  > <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent"
  > ```
  >
  > runat="server">
  >         Other
  >
  > ```
  > <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"
  > ```
  >
  > runat="server">
  >
  > ```
  >     <h2>Upload A File</h2>
  >
  >      <% Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Home")%>
  >        <input type="file" name="f" />
  >        <input type="submit" />
  >        <% Html.EndForm()%>
  >     </form>
  > </asp:Content>
  > ```

  - HomeController.vb

  > _
  >       Public Class HomeController
  >           Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller
  >
  > ```
  >     Function Index() As ActionResult
  >         ViewData("Message") = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!"
  >
  >         Return View()
  >     End Function
  >
  >     Function About() As ActionResult
  >         Return View()
  >     End Function
  >
  >     <HttpPost()> _
  >     Sub UploadFile(f As HttpPostedFileBase) <---Breakpoint here, f is always "Nothing"
  >
  >         RedirectToAction("Other")
  >     End Sub
  >
  >
  >     Function Other() As ActionResult
  >         Return View()
  >     End Function
  > End Class
  > ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `enctype` HTML property for the form to `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: I can't seem to find an example using vb.net

Comment: Me neither, anonymous classes in vb.net seems to be the problem. Though you could always `<form action="/Home/UploadFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`.

Comment: Would it be wise to use C#?  I just clicked through the little MVC2 wizard, and didn't really care which it picked.

Comment: I do prefer C#, if it's the right language for you is well, up to you.

Comment: I changed the project to C#, it works fine now.  My only issue is there is some max file upload size limitation setting in IIS7.5